# Setup Google App Engine as a page on my domain

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using a free domain from cu.cc and also free hosting provided by bytehost. I want to add google app as a page and not for the whole domain. Like the app should open in www.something.cu.cc/google-app-1 and so on. Is it possible? If so how do i set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could think to do it would be to put an iframe on that page e.g.

```
<iframe src="https://1-0-1-dot-someapp.appspot.com/"></iframe>
```

more details on iframes can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: yeah excatly!! so i can keep using my hosting and also have google app on my pages of my site. where as i can also link my site to multiple apps.. way to go... thanks @samson

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, in the sense that you won't be able to have some other host serve some other page on that same domain, because
the [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) procedure only takes a domain name, without a file/page path and mapping is done at DNS level (i.e. entire server/host level).

Comment: so anyway i can have domain email accounts and database services when i am using google app engine?

Comment: DBs yes, email maybe a bit tricky. Docs are here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs, check the ones for environment you plan to use.